# Trouble implementing a gradient background

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I am trying to implement this design on my website- https://kevinhufnagl.com/how-to-stripe-website-gradient-effect/
I have copied most of the code but I am getting an error in the scss code.

```
    --section-gap: calc( #{$standard_space});
    --gradient-padding:120px;
    --gradient-title-margin: 100px;
    --section-skew-Y: -12deg;
    --section-angle-sin: 0.212;
    --transform-origin-x: calc(var(--section-gap) * 0.8);
    @include mq($container_medium_width) {
        --section-gap: calc((100vw - #{$container_medium_width} + #{$standard_space} * 2) / 2);
    }


    .section-title-1 {
        font-size:64px;
        font-weight:700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width:500px;
        max-width:80vw;
        @include mq(450px) {
            font-size:70px;
        }
        @include mq($tablet) {
            font-size:90px;
        }
        @include mq($laptop) {
            font-size:100px;
            width:600px;
        }
    }

    .text {
        line-height: 1;
        margin: var(--gradient-title-margin) 0 0 0;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        min-height: 200px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    .text-above {
        color: var(--font-color);
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .text-under {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .text-under-blended {
        color: #3a3a3a;
        mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
    }
    
    .text-under-overlay {
        opacity: 0.2;
        color: #3a3a3a;
    }

    #gradient-canvas {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        --gradientcolorzero: #6ec3f4;
        --gradientcolorone: #3a3aff;
        --gradientcolortwo: #ff61ab;
        --gradientcolorthree: #E63946;
   }
```

The error is "{ expected" and "at-rule or selector expected" for the first line.
I know there should be some sort of selector maybe, but I don't know what to do exactly. I have used the scss compiler. I have attached the rest of the code here too.
**The HTML code is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="gradient.js" ></script>
    <title>website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <section class="section_top">
        <div class="section-container">
            <div class="section-layout-container container-medium with-padding">
                <div class="section-layout">
                    <div class="gradient-area">
                        <div class="gradient-title-area">
                        <h1 class="text text-above section-title-1"><?= $title ?></h1>
                        <div  class="section_background-wrap">
                            <canvas id="gradient-canvas" data-js-darken-top data-transition-in></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text text-under text-under-blended section-title-1"><?= $title ?></div>
                        <div class="text text-under text-under-overlay section-title-1"><?= $title ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="section-title-2 subtitle"><?= get_field("subtitle")?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant put all the javascript code here because of the character limit but it can be found on the link attached. There it is in the gradient animation file.

Would really appreciate some help on how to implement this! I tried placing some selectors and the code compiled but I would just get a blank screen. I then also got the $standard_space not defined error (this variable is in the first line of the scss code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you’re setting CSS variables outside of a block.

Change your first lines to this:

```css
:root {
    --section-gap: calc( #{$standard_space});
    --gradient-padding:120px;
    --gradient-title-margin: 100px;
    --section-skew-Y: -12deg;
    --section-angle-sin: 0.212;
    --transform-origin-x: calc(var(--section-gap) * 0.8);
    @include mq($container_medium_width) {
        --section-gap: calc((100vw - #{$container_medium_width} + #{$standard_space} * 2) / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! But the design still isn't getting implemented. When I go into the console there are no errors showing. In the sass compiler, I am getting one error though - "Compilation Error
Error: Undefined variable: "$standard-space". Do you know how to fix this? Is it related to the scope?

Comment: There are 2 kinds of variables here: CSS variables (starting with `--`) and Sass variables. In this case, `$standard-space` is a Sass variable, and as the error message says, it is undefined. Presumably in the example you are copying from, it was defined elsewhere, such as in a file with just Sass variables. Just define it yourself at the top as you might any other Sass variable